# PHPStorm bombarded by xdebug remote requests

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

PHPStorm 9 is being hit by non-stop Xdebug requests when I do not have the listener enabled in PHPStorm and I don't have it enabled in the browser Chrome extension.

These windows constantly pop-up disrupting my ability to use the IDE:
[image: incoming connection from xdebug]

This started after I had to disable `xdebug.remote_autostart` setting due to conflicts causing PHP scripts run at the CLI level to hang.

Now every background queue that executes is triggering this incoming connection message.

Every time I delete the server `*.dev` from PHPStorm it shows back up again.

How do I stop this?

Below is the full value list from the Debugger console when these undesired requests come in:
[image: debugger values]

Comment: Your description completely contradicts my experience (and the way how it works): 1) If listener is disabled in PhpStorm then it simply does not listen for incoming connections 2) If `remote_autostart` is disabled then there must be some switch (e.g. query parameter or cookie) that will trigger it -- check your cookies/investigate request parameters (GET/POST data). Another option -- explicit `xdebug_break()` in your code.

Comment: But you have few options: 1) enable ignoring incoming connections if such server does not exist 2) add such request url (if those URLs are the same) to the list of skipped paths -- debug sessions that were initiated from such urls will be ignored by IDE

Comment: 1) There is no parameter that should be triggering this, as you can see in the screenshot I just posted. 2) I am not using `xdebug_break()` anywhere.

Comment: @LazyOne If I click "ignore" then it just re-opens the window again stating it doesn't recognize the incoming connection file path. This appears to be connected to a background Redis queue. I flushed the entire Redis DB and checked to make sure there is nothing relevant that it could be processing, yet these continue to interrupt all other xdebug connections and my ability to use the app.

Comment: @LazyOne I also want to note that the project it is referring to is already mapped, but when the connection comes in, it shows up as `*.dev` instead of the pre-mapped project `site.dev`.

Comment: *" it shows up as *.dev instead of the pre-mapped project site.dev"* Then try that option in #1 -- from IDE point of view `*.dev` is not the same as `site.dev` and if you have no separate entry under `PHP | Servers` then that option should help. Then once again -- if listener is disabled (phone handle icon is off) then IDE should not be accepting any debug connections (if you do not have any other currently active debug session, of course). In any case -- verify that IDE does not listen on xdebug port (e.g. `sudo lsof -nP -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN`).

Comment: After restarting vagrant, this problem went away...or it has for now. Probably due to fact that some queues are long running and were doing so under old `remote_autostart` setting instance.